# Rings where all indecomposable modules are projective or injective

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a semi-perfect noetherian ring.

> Is there a nice classification of such $A$ such that every indecomposable finitely generated $A$-module is projective or injective?

Im also interested in possibly larger classes of rings or even categories, like:

> Is there a classification of abelian categories with nice properties (like Krull-Schmidt) such that every object is a direct sum of projective and/or injective objects?

If $A$ is finite dimensional algebra over an algebraically closed field $K$, the classification is not so hard:

A (we can assume A is connected) is Morita equivalent to one of the following algebras:

-$K$

-$KQ$, where $Q$ is of Dynkin type $A_2$ or of Dynkin type $A_3$ with opposite
orientations.

Such rings $A$ should be of global dimension at most 1:
Let $S$ be a simple $A$-module that is not projective.
Then $\Omega^1(S)$ must be projective (as it does not contain injective direct summands). Thus $pd(S) \leq 1$ for all simples $S$ and thus the global dimension of $A$ is at most $1$. So for Artin algebras one can use the classification of hereditary representation-finite algebras now. The condition furthermore implies that every simple module is projective or injective, so the quiver of the algebra consists only of sources or sinks. Thus the Dynkin type is $A_1,A_2,A_3,B_2,B_3,C_3$ or $G_2$. For types $B_3, C_3$ and $G_2$ there are too many indecomposable modules and those types do not appear.

Comment: You might be interested in `Smith, Patrick F., and Robert Wisbauer. "A note on GV-modules with Krull dimension." Glasgow Mathematical Journal 32.3 (1990): 389-390.` which considered rings in which each simple module is projective or is injective.  They are the so-called "right generalized V-rings."